# Why doesn't this custom table $wpdb query work?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a custom table called wp_purchases that is added to by a Paypal IPN, it has the columns post_id, purchase_id, username, email and changes:

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$post_id = $post->ID;
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->purchases = $table_prefix . 'purchases';
$result = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->purchases WHERE username = $user AND post_id = $post_id");
if ($result) {...
```

I'm just trying to check if there is a purchase under a certain username in a single `.php` theme page and then perform an operation unrelated to the `$result`.
It won't work though, any way I try it comes up with null. Is it something to do with using `$wpdb->purchases` or not including a certain file or something else? I've also tried it with `get_results` and `get_row` with no luck.

Comment: do you need to add quotes around the values (i.e. user='$user').  What is the error you receive if any? i sometimes just echo the query into the page and try it directly on the SQL server to see if i can tweak it till it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$result = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM `".$wpdb->purchases."` WHERE username = '$user' AND post_id = '$post_id';");
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late for this answer, but I'll still post it for the sake of others who are also having similar issue.

You mentioned that the query still returns nothing even after removing the WHERE part, have you tried to echo $wpdb->purchases variable? It might just returning you a string "purchases" instead of "wp_purchases" (assuming that your table prefix is "wp_"). Try using **$wpdb->prefix** instead of **$table_prefix**, or **$wpdb->base_prefix** if you got a multisite.

```
$wpdb->purchases = $wpdb->prefix . 'purchases';
```

Answer (score 1):

I gave up and just used

```
$result = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM wp_purchases WHERE username = $user AND post_id = $post_id");
```

because it's for a single site and doesn't really need the table prefix, it'll always be wp_

Answer (score 0):

What type of `username`? I assume it stores string data. So variable `$user` must be quoted:

`"SELECT * FROM $wpdb->purchases WHERE username = \"$user\" AND post_id = $post_id"`

Comment: thanks for catching that, but even if I leave out the WHERE part of the query it still comes up with nothing :(

Comment: Hi. Have you tried to echo your query instead of executing it right away? Try something like this `$sql="SELECT * FROM $wpdb->purchases WHERE username = \"$user\" AND post_id = $post_id"; echo '<br />sql='.$sql.'<br />'; die();` Then try to execute it in phpmyadmin. If query you got is correct and it is executed without any errors and result is still empty check your table. Maybe it doesn't contain data wich satisfies your `where`-condition.